# Convert object key into variable

Tags: javascript, json, object

I know how to use objects, but I wonder... Is it possible to convert object key like this:

```
{"fname":"peter", "lastname":"parker"}
```

Into this?

```
var fname = "peter";
var lname = "parker";
```

Comment: Why would you do this? Simply access to the object property? Like this: `var fname = yourobject.fname; var lname = yourobject.lastname;`

Comment: You can create global variables from the above by attaching properties into the `window` object (if you are on a browser based execution environment). You cannot possibly introduce dynamically named function scoped (local) variables.

Comment: While this is possible, I would strongly suggest instead assigning the object to a variable with a short name and then doing `o.fname` instead of `fname`.

Comment: Is this what you want [parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: The only solution that may come to my mind involve creating a closure with manually written argument names - nothing really usable. It's not that we all never thought about it, mind you. But in the end it's not just worth the effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know it is old question but a method you could use is:

```
const obj = {"fname":"peter", "lastname":"parker"};
const { fname, lastname } = obj;
console.log(fname); // prints "peter"
console.log(lastname); // prints "parker"
```

Maybe it helps to someone.

Answer (score -1):

Try this to fetch the keys of an object:

```js
var keys = Object.keys({
  fname: "peter",
  lastname: "parker"
});
```

It returns an array with a `length` of `2`, which looks like this:

```js
// keys[0] === "fname";
// keys[1] === "lastname";
```